# INSERT statement not working when using it through a variable in Mule

Tags: database, mule, esb

My database component has the following configuration

```
<db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Database">
        <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[#[flowVars.dbquery]]]></db:dynamic-query>
</db:insert>
```

I have declared the "dbquery" variable as follows

```
<set-variable variableName="dbquery" value="INSERT INTO WBUSER.EMP VALUES('#[payload.FullName]','#[payload.SerialNumber]')" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

On running the application the values inserted into the DB are "#[payload.FullName] and #[payload.SerialNumber].

But when my database component has the following configuration actual values of FullName and SerialNumber are getting inserted into the database.

```
<db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Database">
        <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO WBUSER.EMP VALUES('#[payload.FullName]','#[payload.SerialNumber]')]]></db:dynamic-query>
</db:insert>
```

Here FullName and SerialNumber are not variables. They are column names of the list in the payload as [{FullName=yo, SerialNumber=129329}, {FullName=he, SerialNumber=129329}]. 
Can someone tell me the difference here. And is there a way i can achieve database insertion using just the variable as in the earlier case?

Answer (score 0):

It caused by different approach to insert data. It works correctly for the configuration inside `db-insert`, because the payload is in form of *List* and *Bulk Mode* option selected.

To make it work for the first configuration (declare SQL query in a variable) then you have to do the following steps:

1. Iterate each payload value by utilizing: `collection-splitter`.
2. Deselect *Bulk Mode* from database connector.

The configuration should be:

```
    <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
    <set-variable variableName="dbquery" value="INSERT INTO WBUSER.EMP VALUES('#[payload.FullName]','#[payload.SerialNumber]')" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[#[flowVars.dbquery]]]></db:dynamic-query>
    </db:insert>
```